# Prevent Re-executing the timer

Tags: android, timer

I'm new to Android.
I used a timer to schedule to repeat the method.
I need to stop the timer and there runnable when reloading activity.

here is code.

```
timer = new Timer();
        handlerUpdate = new Handler();

        updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.e("test", "run");
                    updateTickets(printedTicketsJson);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // error, do something
                }
            }
        };
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handlerUpdate.post(updateRunnable);
            };

        };
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 3000);
```

*** I need to stop and restart timer.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html), I think `onResume` is what you're looking for, but the whole thing is probably useful for you

Answer (score 0):

To stop`Timer` use `timer.cancel();` inside your method before reloading activity and after that
to reload activity again call `recreate();`

> Cause this Activity to be recreated with a new instance. This results in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a configuration change -- the current instance will go through its lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it

Comment: thanks Mohammed Farhan,Im developing ticket printing app,so I need to update printed ticket to server in background.also getReservationTickets data method run in doInBackground method,Am i doing correct ways?pls help me

Comment: Ok but why are you using `Timer`? Use `AsyncTask` or other networking library like `Volley` to send the ticket to server. By doing this you will get to know if communication was succesfull or not. If successful then reload the activity again.